# How can I read contents of a text file using PHP & process elements?

Tags: php

I'm trying to read in a name from a text file in PHP and remove spaces in the names, which I do using preg_replace in a function.

```
function fixName($input) {
$input = preg_replace('/[^ \w-]/', ' ', $input);
return $input;
}

echo fixName('BOB     VAN'), "\n";
```

However, I have a text file that has multiple names similar to the one above each on a new line, and I'm trying to figure out how to store those names that are read in from the file and process and output them. Would I do something such as reading the file and storing them into an array?

The text file looks like this

```
ID    FIRST    LAST
348    BOB      VAN
349    ALBERT      JOHN
```

Comment: What kind of processing do you want to do?

Comment: i'm trying to replace all extra spaces in the names in the text file with only 1 space

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read file string by string and store it in an array then you can try something like:

```php
$output = array();
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    $buffer = preg_replace('/[^ \w-]/', ' ', $buffer);
    list($id, $name) = explode(' ', $buffer, 2);
    $output[$id] = $name; //you can index elements by ID or store ID and name as nested array
}
fclose($handle);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: thank you, how would i use this to do the same to the ID as well? I have a method to format the ID

Comment: @johnf  you are welcome, I added this example in my answer

Comment: i seem to be getting an error " Notice: Undefined offset: 1" on line 7, perhaps it has something to do with my text file

Comment: I can't guess, I don't see your entire script